# Python Pandas - Get min value of a column based on other column and group the other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have three columns, they look like this:

```
Symbol    |  Type  |  Date    |  Value
----------------------------------------
Reliance  |  Buy   | 01/03/20 | 230000
Reliance  |  Sell  | 04/03/20 | 980000
Reliance  |  Buy   | 17/03/20 |  97000
TCS       |  Buy   | 10/03/20 | 120000
TCS       |  Buy   | 07/03/20 | 890000
TCS       |  Sell  | 05/03/20 | 300000
```

I want to select the minimum `date` and group `value` column and `type` column. Type column can show buy and sell (only two for a symbol).

The end result would look like this:

```
Symbol    |  Type  |  Date    |  Value
----------------------------------------
Reliance  |  Buy   | 01/03/20 |  327000
Reliance  |  Sell  | 04/03/20 |  980000
TCS       |  Buy   | 05/03/20 | 1010000
TCS       |  Sell  | 05/03/20 |  300000
```

So far I am able to group successfully without the date column. Code looks like this:

```
new_df = the_df.groupby(['symbol_', type_col])[value_col].sum().reset_index()
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
new_df = the_df.groupby(['symbol_', type_col, date_col])[value_col].sum().reset_index()
df_new = new_df[new_df.groupby('symbol_').date_of_initmation_to_company_.transform('min') == new_df[date_col]]
```

But it didn't work as expected. Actually the second like with `.transform` didn't do any changes. Can you show me the right way to do it?

Comment: It is not make sense , you add the later buy to previous buy date

Comment: I am consolidating the values and only want start date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then

```
out = df.groupby(['Symbol','Type']).agg({'Date' : 'first' , 'Value' : 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: There's an issue there. It gets the first value no matter if it's min or max. Can I use 'min'?

Comment: @TheOnlyAnilT yes you can , df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date); out = df.groupby(['Symbol','Type']).agg({'Date' : 'min' , 'Value' : 'sum'}).reset_index()